# Loop to iterate between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns. 'refresh' and 'model'. I'm trying to write a loop that checks, per row, if 'refresh' and 'model' are the same. If the values between 'refresh' and 'model' are the same then do nothing.
If the values between the 'refresh' and 'model' rows are different then the value in 'refresh' column should be replaced with nan and dropped. Then, rows in 'refresh' shift one up.

This should be repeated until the row across 'refresh' and 'model' are the same. 'model' column should remain unchanged

```
# Example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'refresh': [1, '1a', '1b', 2, 3, 4, 5, '5a', '5b', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'model': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, nan, nan, nan, nan]})


# Desired output

    |refresh | model| 
    |--------|----|
    |1       | 1  |
    |2       | 2  |
    |3       | 3  |
    |4       | 4  |
    |5       | 5  |
    |6       | 6  |
    |7       | 7  |
    |8       | 8  |
    |9       | 9  |
    |10      | 10 | 
    |nan     | nan|
    |nan     | nan|
    |nan     | nan|
    |nan     | nan|
```

I have tried the following but not been successful:

```
# Create example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'refresh': [1, '1a', '1b', 2, 3, 4, 5, '5a', '5b', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'model': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, nan, nan, nan, nan]})

# Define columns to check for equality
col1 = 'refresh'
col2 = 'model'

# Loop through each row of the DataFrame
i = 0
while i < len(df):
    
    # Check if the values in the specified columns are the same
    if df.loc[i, col1] == df.loc[i, col2]:
        
        # Move to the next row
        i += 1
    else:
        # Replace the value in the column with NaN
        df.loc[i, col1] = np.nan

        # Drop the NaN and shift the rows up
        df = df.dropna(subset=[col1])
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
        
        # Reset index to reflect the shifted rows
        i = 0

# Print the updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

Edit: output of the above

```
  refresh  model
0       1      1
```

Note, Chat-GPT produces the following solution but it doesn't seem to end when running?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'refresh': [1, '1a', '1b', 2, 3, 4, 5, '5a', '5b', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'model': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

# loop until the values in 'refresh' and 'model' are the same across a row
while not all(df['refresh'] == df['model']):
    # iterate over each row
    for i in range(len(df)):
        # check if the values in 'refresh' and 'model' are the same
        if df.loc[i, 'refresh'] == df.loc[i, 'model']:
            # do nothing
            pass
        else:
            # replace the value in 'refresh' column with NaN
            df.loc[i, 'refresh'] = np.nan
            # shift rows in 'refresh' column up
            if i < len(df)-1:
                df.loc[i, 'refresh'] = df.loc[i+1, 'refresh']
            else:
                df.loc[i, 'refresh'] = np.nan

# drop any remaining NaN values
df.dropna(inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail than "not been successful"?

Comment: Are you essentially setting the column refresh to be a copy of the data from the column model?

Comment: In your dataframe, only the first row match your condition model == refresh

Comment: @bgun. It's exactly what I said. Only the first row match...

Comment: @Corralien you are correct. Only the first row matches. Therefore, what would happen is that Refresh row two '1a 'becomes na and is dropped, then '1b' becomes na, and is dropped, until it becomes 2. Then, as the rows in Refresh and model are equal, we then move to row 3

Comment: In your example "desired output", the `refresh` column ends up with exactly the same contents as `model`. Is there any scenario where that would not be true?

Answer (score 0):

In case you only care about the final result, you can achieve it with just one line.

```py
df = pd.merge(df[['refresh']], df[['model']], left_on='refresh', right_on='model', how='right')
```

Comment: Unfortunately the actual df is too large for this solution and exceeds memory. I have also tried str.contains & list comprehension (as actual df uses strings), however, this doesn't produce the desired result